# Creating a static method that builds a RadioButton returns a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, static, nullpointerexception, android-radiobutton

So i have this `static` method whose building a RadioButton:

```
public static RadioButton createARadioButton()
{
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(null);
    return radioButton;
}
```

And i have this assignment statement:

```
radioButton = createARadioButton();
```

Which gives me a NullPointerExeption.

Now how do i write a static method that will create a RadioButton that will perform good?
What am i doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass in a null Context argument for `RadioButton`. At the least you need something like this:

```
public static RadioButton createARadioButton(Context context)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(context);
    return radioButton;
}
```